# Порядок отрисовки геометрии в Unity3d

Tags: unity3d, шейдеры, shader-graph

Два 3d объекта со сложной геометрией расположены "друг в друге". Нужно чтобы объект **Outer** всегда рисовался поверх объекта **Inner**, даже если **Inner** частично или полностью "выпирает" перед объектом **Outer**. Простая смена **Render Queue** в материале ничего не меняет. Нечто очень похожее получается, если вместе с указанием очереди 2000+ прописать **ZWrite Off**, но такой объект начинает "просвечивать" в самых неожиданных для меня местах и ситуациях - SkyBox всегда будет рисоваться поверх этого объекта, если за ним нет другой геометрии. Или если объект сложной формы (или Cull Off) - то сквозь него будет видно его же самого.

В рунете информации не нашел, кроме бесполезных фраз "нужно писать свою z-сортировку", а в англоязычной пока не знаю что именно искать. Используется URP, если это важно.

Вариант с несколькими камерами не подходит - объектов со своим "приоритетом" отрисовки предполагается до десятка штук в одном месте

*Пример - внутренний объект "выпирает" сквозь внешний, стрелками указано то что должно быть скрыто*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: *"нужно писать свою z-сортировку"* - это верное направление

Comment: Если URP, то там по слоям можно настроить.